# Mopub ad doesn't show when using personal ad unit id

Tags: android, mopub

I've integrated Mopub into my Android project using Fabric. I can get the full screen ad to show when using the test id.

But when I use my personal ad unit id for the ad, it does not work.

I believe I have set the ad up through Marketplace on Mopub's dashboard, but maybe I am missing something?

Here are the error logs:

```
D/MoPub: Failed to retrieve GPS location: access appears to be disabled.
D/MoPub: Failed to retrieve network location: access appears to be disabled.
I/MoPub: Ad failed to load.
D/MoPub: Interstitial load failed: No ads found.
```

Comment: let me know when you find any solution of this issue. please share with me

Comment: No ads found is expected when there is no ad found to match your profile. Especially when you use an emulator or don't pass your location like in your example.